# Почему не подключается css в React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Например я импортирую компонент из библиотеки:

```
import Datetime from 'react-datetime'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
```

Но в браузере компонент выводится без стилей

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно установить `css-loader`

```
npm install css-loader --save-dev
```

Затем нужно добавить его в загрузчики в конфигурации `webpack`

```
module.exports = {
//...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      //...
    ]
  }
};
```

Ну и потом уже сможете использовать `css`

```
import Datetime from 'react-datetime';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```

Comment: я не испльую webpack

Comment: @JonnyManowar  а что используешь? Как проект собираешь?

Comment: Все делаю через npm

Comment: @JonnyManowar тогда самое время изучить какой-нибудь сборщик, без него дальше будет только сложнее.

Comment: но надо чтоб npm понимал что с ним делать дальше

Comment: @JonnyManowar ну вот что говорит сама документация `create-react-app` - Вам нужно поместить любые JS и CSS-файлы внутрь `src` , иначе `Webpack` их не увидит.
Ну и в той же документации написано, что нужно использовать `Webpack` - https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-stylesheet

Comment: это как то костыльно. npm же и нужен что бы все сторонние библиотеки были в отдельной папке а не в папке с проектом

Comment: @JonnyManowar ну так и используй сборщик, все `npm` пакеты будут сохранятся в `node-modules`, а в проект будешь их импортировать и все. NPM - это менеджер пакетов, не более. Как ты будешь собирать проект, в котором у тебя и картинки, и шрифты, и всякие пост- препроцессоры? Однажды правильно настроенный конфиг того же `webpack` на долгое время избавляет от головной боли.

Comment: Дело ещё в том, что npm это Node Package Manager, а мы собираем проект не для ноды, а для браузера. Браузер не знает про ноду, про node_modules и т.п. Браузер знает теги типа <script> и <link>. Поэтому и нужен вебпак (или роллап, или браузерифай, хотя с ними я не работал). Вебпак с помощью лоадеров приводит все наши зависимости к виду commonjs модулей (включая стили, сасс, графику, шрифты). Отдельные плагины позволяют бандлить тектовые файлы и другие типы файлов отдельно от js кода

Comment: кстати, я заметил, что Джонни никогда не говорит спасибо!

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko спасибо за разъяснение, думаю, что Джонни врядли это увидит. Наверное нужно было его имя в комменте указать

Comment: И Вам спасибо! Кстати я ещё думал сегодня с утра, вебпак также помогает организовать разные окружения (дев/продакшн) в проекте, интегрировать переменные окружения в клиентский код, что тоже крайне удобно. Удачи!